# iOS Map View - Cannot show map type segmented control

Tags: ios, mapkit

my project (iOS8) has a number of MKMapViews. In each, there is the map itself and a segmented control showing map types. In all but one, the segmented control works. I cannot figure what is different about the last control.

In the storyboard, it looks like this:

[image]

and in XML, this section is as follows:

```
 <!--Station Maps-->
        <scene sceneID="LeM-5s-2wf">
            <objects>
                <viewController title="Station Maps" id="hYA-cM-abP" customClass="StationMapViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="2a8-lC-bPP"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="QcK-rg-ebO"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="kcf-sT-UDP">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <mapView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" mapType="standard" showsUserLocation="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yI9-me-Rg3">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="600" height="558"/>
                            </mapView>
                            <segmentedControl opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="top" segmentControlStyle="bar" selectedSegmentIndex="0" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="s2b-eX-v5B">
                                <rect key="frame" x="201" y="551" width="199" height="30"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="199" id="Bgo-vH-Ovn"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="29" id="pWC-nC-aW4"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <segments>
                                    <segment title="Standard"/>
                                    <segment title="Satellite"/>
                                    <segment title="Hybrid"/>
                                </segments>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="setMapType:" destination="hYA-cM-abP" eventType="valueChanged" id="gTQ-TR-i69"/>
                                </connections>
                            </segmentedControl>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="yI9-me-Rg3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="kcf-sT-UDP" secondAttribute="leading" id="7QQ-MR-baI"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="yI9-me-Rg3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2a8-lC-bPP" secondAttribute="bottom" id="Xg4-Br-oo6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="s2b-eX-v5B" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="yI9-me-Rg3" secondAttribute="centerX" id="e3O-oO-939"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="yI9-me-Rg3" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-2" id="kHP-sZ-bNy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QcK-rg-ebO" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="s2b-eX-v5B" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="kQT-6C-SAu"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="s2b-eX-v5B" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="kcf-sT-UDP" secondAttribute="centerX" id="klk-9a-NAw"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <toolbarItems>
                        <barButtonItem title="Item" id="oHZ-CA-um6"/>
                    </toolbarItems>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="hfj-yd-fhd">
                        <barButtonItem key="leftBarButtonItem" title="Back" id="jFM-Qu-SCe">
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="back:" destination="hYA-cM-abP" id="fHl-I4-6Bu"/>
                            </connections>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </navigationItem>
                    <nil key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
                    <nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>
                    <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
                    <size key="freeformSize" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="mapView" destination="yI9-me-Rg3" id="5tl-Dc-5bi"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ZGT-3J-F3u" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="10204" y="2917"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
```

I have tried swapping the positions of the map view and the segmented control by literally moving one above the other, or below the other, as well as highlighting an element and using Arrange > send Back/Forward.

So, any insight would be really welcome.

Comment: I also tried deleting the segmented control and reinstalling it.

Comment: I got around this by adding the control programmatically.